# What determines your USERPROFILE Environment Variable when launching a .NET app

Tags: c#, .net, windows, operating-system, registry

I have a .net/C# application when launched on a test server running VMWARE / Windows Server 2008, receives a USERPROFILE Environment Variable pointing to C:\windows\system32\config\systemprofile, but other applications seemingly built in a similar fashion inhert the correct value of C:\Users\{username}.

A slight twist - the application receives the correct value when run locally on my development machine.  So I'm thinking this is a profile/registry issue with some combination of setting in my app.

The issues is manifested when you attempt to open an OpenFileDialog or similar.  You get the exception "Location is not available: C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop refers to a location that is unavailable..."

Any ideas?

UPDATE:  The application is WPF running web services against IIS via WCF.  Locally in development I am using IISExpress.  I've found that after touching the WCF services in the client, the application inherits the APPDATA and USERPROFILE of the IIS AppPool the services are running under.  If I adjust the AppPool values to use my user account instead of ApplicationPoolDefault and set LoadUserProfile = true - things work.  Obviously this is a bad thing.  As an alternative, I cache off the environment variables when the WPF app runs, and after it initially connects to WCF, I reset the variables.  This appears to get around the issue but I'd like to solve it a better way but I have no idea what is influencing this behavior in WCF and my IIS Services.

Comment: Are you launching the process programmatically using `Process.Start`? Is the process being started from a Windows Service?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The value is present when we launch the app from the exe on the desktop.  It also manages spawning other processes using Process.Start, as well as hosting dll's in child AppDomains. But they all wind up inheriting the same value from the parent.  I have another application which can also launch the same processes, but that app (as hinted at above) receives the correct value and thus, child processes also inherit the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

It might have to deal with what account the web app is running under in IIS.  You can change it from the default "Network Service" account to an actual user account.

Comment: Where does it say that this is a web app?

Comment: The application is a WPF front-end using WCF to connect to IISExpress Server.

Comment: Actually, to be more accurate.  On the server its being deployed on IIS directly, and not IISExpress.  The client still connects.  There are environment variables regarding the AppPool in the client.  Not sure if that is in indicator meaning somehow using WCF and our setup loads the incorrect profile.

Comment: Thanks for the detail, I should have asked.